# New Line Inside a Spreadsheet Cell in csv file using tcl

Tags: csv, tcl, cell, newline

I'm trying to output this result to a csv file using Tcl.
I just know that to make all the words into each column is using "," and excel uses ALT + ENTER.
What if i want to create a new line inside a spreadsheet cell in csv file using tcl?

```
set fo [open test.csv w]
puts $fo "Banana,Yellow,10,10,10,Nice color Can eat"
puts $fo "Apple,Green,20,5,8, Not enough"
```

Example :

Output: 
1st row:

Banana Yellow 10 10 10  Nice color

```
                       Can eat
```

Apple  Green  20  5  8   Not enough

Comment: I've run your code - created csv is totally OK. No break line after color

Comment: I was trying to inject new line into the same field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inject a newline into the field, enclose the field in quotes and add a newline character:

```
set fo [open test.csv w]
puts $fo "Banana,Yellow,10,10,10,\"Nice color\nCan eat\""
puts $fo "Apple,Green,20,5,8,\"Not enough\""
close $fo
```

LibreOffice opens that csv file like this:

[image]

If you're expecting "Can eat" to show up in row 2 column F, you'll need to find a way to write

```
puts $fo {Banana,Yellow,10,10,10,"Nice color"}
puts $fo {,,,,,"Can eat"}
puts $fo {Apple,Green,20,5,8,"Not enough"}
```

Comment: Im trying to inject a newline into the same field which exact as your picture show. However, the software to open the csv file is Excel 2013. 
I've run your code, the "color Can eat" words are gone.